# EhCache Memory limit

Tags: caching, ehcache

In my code I am using EhCache to store an object. Code is below

```
@Resource(name = "ehCacheManager")
private CacheManager manager;
private Ehcache cache;
public void testCache(){    
 cache = manager.getCache("ehSubjects");
 for loop to read subjects data{ //This loops runs 15051 times
 final Element element = new Element(subject.subjectId(), subject);
 cache.put(element);
 }
}
System.out.println("Cache Size:"+cache.getSize()); //15000
```

The issue is there are 15051 subjects objects but when after the loop I try to print the cache size it always gives me 15000.

So is there a limit on the amount of objects we can keep in EhCache?

Comment: Please add any relevant configuration information for Ehcache. Hard to answer otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the ehcache.xml defined by the other team mate. He has given the maxitemsincache value as 15000 due to which cahce was ignoring other items.